# deconstruct a compound tuple in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a function that returns a tuple of which one item is also a tuple.

```
def foo: (Any, (Any, Any))
```

The actual types are not really `Any` but this is a simplification of the actual code (hence I dub this a compound tuple for the sake of this question).

Now I deconstruct this tuple like follows, wishing to proceed computation with a1, a2, a3.

```
val (a1, bar) = foo
val (a2, a3) = bar
```

Is there a one liner for this?

Answer (score 5):

Of course! You can pattern match it the same way.

```
def foo: (Any, (Any, Any)) = (1, (2, 3))

scala> val (a1, (a2, a3)) = foo
a1: Any = 1
a2: Any = 2
a3: Any = 3
```

This works because you have a `Tuple2[Any, Tuple2[Any, Any]]`, and `Tuple2` has an `unapply` method defined that allows this pattern matching to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

```
val (a1, (a2, a3)) = foo
```

Comment: Thanks so much. by the way, do you ever find yourself returning tuples, or do you hammer out a class for every single function return..... I keep oscillating between the two

Comment: The disadvantage of returning a tuple is that from just looking at the return type it's hard to understand what the returned value means. If you use a class, it's much easier to see what the result means.

Comment: ...at the cost of type boilerplate when you write really functional code.

Comment: So how about syntax sugar of declaring case classes inline? `def foo(…): Foo(amount: Int, temperature: Double)`

Comment: @ziggystar That is not valid Scala syntax, as far as I know.

Comment: @Jesper Was just posting and hoping that someone will file a SIP.

Comment: @ziggystar why don't post a SIP yourself if you think this is a worthwile feature?

Comment: I might, if I can allocate the time

Comment: @matt @ziggystar How is that different from a structural type (which exists now, even if the implementation isn't ideal)? Can you use the `Foo` type anywhere else?

Comment: Care to show how a structural type may be used here? Anyway they use reflection (as per [here](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#structural)) so I would keep at arm's length. @ziggystar's implied suggestion feels much better on first look, but it will be quite a fundamental change I suspect; maybe that's why they degressed to reflection with structural types. I guess this should go in scala-debate...

Answer (score 1):

A side note, the nested tuple can be extracted/pattern-matched and further computed via a for comprehension like this,

```
val x = (1,(2,3))
for ( (a,(b,c)) <- Seq(x) ) yield a+b+c
```

Also consider matching on type,

```
val y = (1,("bb",3))
for ( (_,(b:String,_)) <- Seq(x) ) yield b
```

or similarly as already depicted,

```
val (a:Int, (b: Double, c: String)) = (1, (2.0, "ccc"))
a: Int = 1
b: Double = 2.0
c: String = ccc
```

Comment: Thanks, and also as a side note, a `case` should be used rather than a simple `val` or `for` comprehension deconstruction, for elegantly deconstructing inside a `map` function, e.g. when mapping a `Future` of tuples